# How do I output my tex from an array to the screen dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I am new to React and building a quote generator. I want to pull out one quote at a time from my array and show it on the screen, however I can only seem to output each quote to the console.

I have:
1.Created an on click handler and function so that when the user clicks my quote array is targeted.
2. In this function I have created a variable to hold my random array index
3. I have console.logged the array index to see if every time the user clicks it the quote appears.

Component and function and click handler, as you can see the Quote Component should return the quote from the array in my opinion but nothing happens:

```
class Card extends Component {
  state =  {
    quotes: ['"A dream doesn\'t become reality through magic; it takes sweat, determination and hard work."','"You GOT this!"','"To be or not to be that is the question"'];


  changeQuoteHandler = (event) => {
    const quotes = [...this.state.quotes];
    const arrayIndex = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)] 
    console.log(arrayIndex); 

     this.setState({ 
       quotes: quotes
     })
  };

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="Card">
        <div>
          <h2>Random Quote Generator</h2>
          <Quote className="QuoteStyle" quote={this.state.quotes.arrayIndex}/>
        </div>
        <div className="Flex">
          <div>
            <NewQuoteButton onClick={this.changeQuoteHandler}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
};

export default Card;
```

Quote Componenet :

```
import React from 'react';

const Quote = (props) => {
  return(
      <p>{props.quote}</p>
  )
};

export default Quot
```

I would like to print one quote at a time to the screen on click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are so close. You can store the `arrayIndex` that you generate in the state and use it to display the quote. The code would look like something below

```
  class Card extends Component {
    state =  {
      quotes: ['"A dream doesn\'t become reality through magic; it takes sweat, determination and hard work."','"You GOT this!"','"To be or not to be that is the question"'],
      selectedIndex: 0,
    }


    changeQuoteHandler = (event) => {
      const quotes = [...this.state.quotes];
      const arrayIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) % quotes.length);

       this.setState({ 
         quotes: quotes,
         selectedIndex: arrayIndex,
       });
    };

    render(){
      return (
        <div className="Card">
          <div>
            <h2>Random Quote Generator</h2>
            <Quote className="QuoteStyle" quote={this.state.quotes[this.state.selectedIndex]}/>
          </div>
          <div className="Flex">
            <div>
              <NewQuoteButton onClick={this.changeQuoteHandler}/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  };

  export default Card;
```

Comment: thank you @Panther I see your logic here... I tried this and it still doesn't print to screen is there anything else i need to do?

Comment: the you should check your `Quote` component. A single quote is choosen and is sent to it. Its up to the component to display it.

Comment: Hello Panther ok I think I understand what you are saying. I have updated my question with my Quote component. I know here I pass one quote as a property, but when I write props.quotes noting changes either. Is there something I am doing wrong. Thank you

Comment: @AngelaInniss Have updated this with a working codepen. hope that helps. https://codepen.io/marudhupandiyang/pen/vYBwMNB